# I can't migrate at another database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, migrate

I have well working project on local. I use postresql.
Ok. I create another database in postgres locally and specify new name/user/password in settings.py of project.
When I do

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
```

I get error as

```
relation 'report_person' not exist
```

And I have tried delete (and not delete) directory 'migrations'. delete **pycache**. I tried specify Sqlite3 as database - but the same error.

Why I ask?
My project don't want to work with another database)
I succesfully push project on heroku. Specify parameters in settings.py. Create postgresql. But I can't make migrate on heroku) the same error.
I do makemigrations and git commit before push on heroku, but no result
Help me please.
Thank you
Have a nice day!

Comment: Could you try to run 'python manage.py migrate' with all your migrations and not 'python manage.py makemigrations' ? I suppose that you already have all the migrations and you need to apply them, not create new one.

Comment: @OleksandrDashkov  Yes I have tried to run makemigrations with my database succesfully. After I change database in settings.py  After I run migrate in new database - the same error. I try to create table in new database as 'report_person' and I get error 'permission denied for relation report_person' It is magic)

Comment: Do you have a creation of 'report_person' in your migrations?

Comment: @OleksandrDashkov oh ok. I understand this problem. I have a PersonForm in forms.py after delete it migrations ran succesfully. Text of this form in my answer. And I haven't explicity in this questuon.

Answer (score 0):

try migrating with --fake

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
python manage.py migrate yourappname --fake
```

and then again

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Also I think that it's not a good idea to run migrate --fake with the new DB. He will have an empty DB and passed migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I can't explain this situation. All problems in one little model.

It is from models.py:

```
from django import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

This part of forms.py (crazy):

```
from django import form

q = models.Person.objects.all()
qty = range(len(q))
PersonForm = type('PersonForm',
                                (forms.Form,),
                                {'person'+'_'+str(q[i].id): forms.BooleanField(label=q[i].name,
                                        required=False) for i in qty})
```

And I must before migrations delete this 'PersonForm'. Then migrate will be succesfully in new any database. And after migrations I put this form again.
Ok. I don't undestand, why?)

Comment: because you have a query in the file and not in the class/function. When you run migrations, django execute this file and try to execute this file. Your model doesn't exist yet and you have your exception

Comment: @OleksandrDashkov Aaa. Thank you very much!